# Resetting custom UITableViewCell height when iPhone is rotated

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am overloading the delegate method `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and using `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` to programmatically set the height of the cell, based on the text in that cell:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case(kAboutViewOverviewSection): {
      switch (indexPath.row) {
        case(kAboutViewOverviewSectionRow): {
          NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"kAboutViewOverviewSectionFieldText", @"");
          CGSize s = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 500)];
          return s.height + 13;
        }
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    default: {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 44.0;
}
```

This works when the table is first drawn. However, when I change the orientation of the device, from portrait to landscape, the cell height does not change.

I tried overriding the `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method in my table view controller:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  return YES;
}
```

This should reload the table data and (presumably) redraw the table cell views. But this does not have any effect.

Is there a way to force a cell to redraw with a new height, when the device is rotated?

**EDIT**: I have tried the following, to no effect:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is what the application looks like in portrait orientation:

[image: Portait]

Here is what the application looks like in landscape orientation:

[image: Landscape]

There is a gap between the top and bottom edges of the content.

**EDIT 2**:

Adjusting the size parameter via the table frame's width helped fix this display issue:

```
CGSize s = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([tableView frame].size.width,500)];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's less than optimal, but the simplest solution is to call `-reloadData` on the table.

A better solution would be to call `-beginUpdates`, `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, and `-endUpdates` or simply `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` if targeting 3.0 only. This will add animation.

Edit: And you will also need a proper `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize textSize = [[self textForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([tableView frame].size.width - 20, 500)];
    return textSize.height + 13.0f;
}
```

(where `textForRowAtIndexPath:` is a method that returns the cell's text)

Comment: I tried -reloadSections:withRowAnimation: in the -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and this does not work, either.

Comment: These all work if called after the view has been resized. That means they should be in your didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: Also, you appear to always be returning the same size. You should feed the width of the table into -sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: rather that using a hard-coded CGSize

Comment: -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: does not work, either. Additionally, the CGSize parameter in -sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: specifies the maximum possible size. The width of the cell is drawn correctly, but not the height.

Comment: My point is you are returning the same height each time. The row won't change size if you don't provide a different value. For simplicity, return [tableView frame].size.width*0.25; to start, and then work from there

Comment: Okay, setting the CGSize width via [tableView frame].size.width seemed to help. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to cause an infinite loop with the latest iOS

Comment: Mark: `UITableView` was changed such that it needs to know the size of a cell before it can return a cell. I've updated the sample to depend on a new `textForRowAtIndexPath:` method that returns only the text for a row.